# how to add special character to All Lines in EditText or in String?

Tags: java, android

i hope you are fine.
i want a way to add a special character to begenning of every new Line (to the line break), for example i have this text line by line :

```
Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. 
Many students define paragraphs in terms of length. 
a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences. 
a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality. 
though, the unity and coherence of ideas among. 
sentences is what constitutes a paragraph.
```

and i want it to be like this (with "-" in every beginning of line) :

```
-Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. 
-Many students define paragraphs in terms of length. 
-a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences. 
-a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality. 
-though, the unity and coherence of ideas among. 
-sentences is what constitutes a paragraph.
```

and this is my small code :

```
String string = edittext1.getText().toString();

//here i want to add code for adding a "special character like -+*" in every new line

textview1.setText(string);
```

and thank you in advance.

Comment: Which part presents a problem?

Comment: for example i have long text with multiple lines and i want to add a special character like "-" character in every line break

Comment: `string = "\u2022 " + string.replaceAll("\\R", "$0\u2022 ");` (bullet here)

Comment: I understand your task. Seems pretty straightforward. So what stops **you** from completing it on your own?  Where exactly are **you** stuck?

Comment: what i want is to generate the new text edited automatically (programatically) because i deal with many texts, this one just example

Comment: thanks so much for your answer brother i will try the code now

Comment: very usefull this code, thank you again brother   
this added a point for every line 
can i change it to add " - " ?
if not there's no problem i use point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do that

```
    String string = edittext1.getText.toString; 

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(); 

    String[] array = string.split("\\n"); 

    for(String line : array){ 
         result.append("-").append(line).append("\n"); 

          }

    textview1.setText(result);
```

Comment: The delimiter needs to be "\n"

Comment: thanks for answer brother, it is almost done your beautiful idea, just i have one error 
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to ArrayList<String>"
what should i do

Comment: this correction work fine

String string = edittext1.getText.toString;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        //ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.split(".")));
        String[] array = string.split("\\.");

        for(String line : array){

            result.append("-").append(line).append("\n");

        }

Comment: that works for me bro
but i get the " - " in the first line only
how can i make it add it to all beginning of break lines

Comment: try this string.split("\\n"); 
instead of string.split("\\.");

Comment: DONE brother thanks so much 
this is the full code is someone need it :
String string = edittext1.getText().toString(); 
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(); 
String[] array = string.split("\\n"); 
for(String line : array)
{ 
result.append("-").append(line).append("\n"); 
textview1.setText(result);
}

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you should just be editing the strings directly, but in this case, maybe make a third-string and for that string concatenate the individual lines of text as strings with a string that contains "-" so now you can print your desired strings one line at a time with \n to separate the lines.

Comment: can you brother give me a pratical example plz

Comment: @HishamKanon just do System.out.println("prefix" + "String")

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by replacing the charSequence with new one as you want.

**Kotlin Code Example**
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html

**Java Code Example**
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace